# Node FetchError: invalid json response body - unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I'm trying to get the response from my server route I'm getting this error: `FetchError: invalid json response body - unexpected token < in JSON`

I think the problem is when I do `response.json()`?

When I use Postman to reach the same endpoint I got the response that I want. What is happening here?

note: my api tokens can be publicly used

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const TRANSLINK_TOKEN = 'j2bXKzENILvyoxlZ399I'
const TRANSLINK_URL = 'http://api.translink.ca/rttiapi/v1/buses?apikey='

// API routes
app.get('/buses/location', (req, res) => {
  const apiURL = `${TRANSLINK_URL}${TRANSLINK_TOKEN}`
  console.log(apiURL)

  fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("response ok")
        response.json()
        .then((data) => {
          res.json(data)
        })
      }
      else {
        res.sendStatus(response.status)
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        alert(error.message)
    })
})



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

You API return XML not json, please make sure that apiURL return valid json object

to check the response please put `console.log(data)` before `res.json(data)`

You can use [XML2JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) package to convert the response to json format or use `res.send(data)` to retrieve xml response as is

```
fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        console.log("response ok");
        console.log(response.body);
          // Add XML2JSON to convert body 
        res.send(response.body);
      }
      else {
        res.sendStatus(response.status)
      }
    })
```

Comment: I'm unable to `console.log(data)` because the error get thrown before it reaches there.

Comment: Sorry please change `response.json().then(...` to be response.then(...` and change `res.json(data)` to be `res.send(data)`  and add `console.log` before `res.send(data)`  to be your final code  `response.then((data) => {
console.log(data);          
res.send(data)
        })
 ` please  note that `response.json()` will not convert xml to json it will convert the json text to json object so you have to use XML2JSON package